# stored procedure, views and functions are not comming on dump file

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump -u parul -p 'db_database' > filelatest_29June.sql
```

I am trying to use this command on unix server database is exported but only tables and data is exported remaining SP's, views, functions are not coming.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11006/67268

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
mysqldump --routines -u parul -p 'db_database' > filelatest_29June.sql
```

The routines flag will output stored procedures and functions, triggers should be included as part of a standard mysqldump.

Regards,

James